# Set paths in C program for executing external programs

Tags: c

I wrote my program in C which includes calling a bash script and another external program from it (all of them located in the same directory as my C program). I set the path of the executing files strict so like:

```
    char *path_for_the_script = "location/of/script.sh";
```

and compile my program.c without any special arguments..

Now I wonder how can I manage that this path gets set by the program, so that someone else could use it from his computer without changing the paths manually?

Comment: You could use `argv[0]` and trim your executable name.

Comment: This is a rather broad question about a common general problem, which can be solved in a variety of different ways, e.g. environment variables, config files, command line params, etc. Look at how existing command line tools handle this kind of configuration option and pick one or more methods that work for your particular use case.

Comment: Do you know about `PATH`? Or place the .sh file in the same dir.

Comment: Well extracting `argue[0]` will not work if you are in the directory and call your program with `./my_program`

Comment: And the sh file is placed in the same directory, but how can I know where the user will save it! I know what PATH is, so you suggest that i add the paths for my files from my C code?

Comment: @malajedala: as far as i know (and i have just tested it again to be sure) `argv[0]` always contains the full path try: `printf("%s",argv[0]);` (run with `$ ./a.out`).  but if you want to allow the user to locate the scripts anywhere he want than you have to tell that path your app using environment variables, commandline parameters, config file, ...

Answer (score 1):

Load the path from a environment variable (also add a fallback or failure path if the variable is not set) and have your program being launched through a wrapper script, which the user can adjust.

Example

in yourprogram.c

```
char const * const path_for_the_script = gentenv("YOURPROGRAM_SCRIPT_PATH");
```

the programlauncher.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
export YOURPROGRAM_SCRIPT_PATH="..."
exec yourprogram $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the path in your code, create a text file in the same directory and fetch the path information from the txt file. Thus anyone can modify the text file with required path and execute the program, with out any code modification.

```
create a file in same directory as source.txt
vi source.txt
location/of/script.sh
```

In your program, use file open operation and access the file contents and assign to path_for_the_script char buffer. This method works only when all the users share the same computer.